# Use an automatically generated Item Object with different XmlElementAttribute

Tags: c#

I need to get the object Item ONLY when it is of type Company.
Here is the automatically generated code from the corresponding xsd:

```
        private object itemField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Company", typeof(Company), Order=1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Customer", typeof(Customer), Order=1)]
    public object Item {
        get {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Item");
        }
    }
```

The class Company is the following :

```
public partial class Company : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string companyNameField;

    private CompanyCompanyType companyTypeField;

    private string companyIDField;

    private string commissionCodeField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string CompanyName {
        get {
            return this.companyNameField;
        }
        set {
            this.companyNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CompanyName");
        }
    }
```

I tried to do something like that in my code :

```
(Company)Item.CompanyName
```

but this can be null reference when the Item object is of Type Customer...
Could you help me please?

Comment: I suppose you mean `((Company)Item).CompanyName`, don´t you? `Item` is of type `object` which has no definition for a `CompanyName`.

Comment: Why don´t you simply check *if* the `Item` is of type `Company`? If so do the cast, otherwise cast to `Customer`.